# Any unix utility/tool to auto backup files before saving?

Tags: vim, backup

I would like to know if there is any existing unix utility or tool that would make a backup of a file with a date/timestamp appended to the filename.

Basically I am looking to automatically make backup of my config files like the `.bashrc`, `.vimrc`, etc when I change the file and save using some text editor.

`vim` specific solution would also be helpful. May be adding some kind of hook only for specific files that creates a copy of the previously saved file and then goes on to save the currently modified file.

Comment: Closest I can think of would be [incron](http://linuxaria.com/article/incron-cron-inotify?lang=en) or something similar. It won't back up before the change but you can use it to backup after a change (but this becomes a lot of a finer/moot point after you get one or two revisions into things) and you can use `tmpwatch` to clean out old revisions after a certain amount of time.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tool, but then again I haven't looked. **However**, you say *Unix*. Which Unix are you talking about? I imagine that something like this would be pretty system-specific, so it might help specifying the environment more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a simple backup scheme that appends a `.YYYYMMDD[a-z]` extension, too.

For that, I've written a set of Vim plugins and scripts: The [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) defines a `:W[riteBackup]` command in Vim that makes a backup of the current file.

With the [writebackupAutomator plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3940), you can have Vim make the backup automatically.

And the [writebackupVersionControl plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1829) offers you additional commands from "real" version control systems, like diffing and moving through history.

In addition to the Vim plugins, I also provide the basic writebackup functionality outside of Vim as VBScript and Bash Shell script versions [on my personal website](http://ingo-karkat.de/downloads/tools/writebackup/index.html); maybe those are helpful to you or at least provide a starting point!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Vim to make backups automatically in [various ways](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_incremental_backups_of_edited_files). For example, I think you could hook into the [`writebackup` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828) for certain file groups.

The [CopyFS](http://boklm.eu/copyfs/) filesystem keeps copies of all old versions of the files stored on it.

But I don't recommend either of these approaches. The best way to keep backups of old file versions — which is a good thing — is to keep them under [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). A simple version control system such as [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) takes about ½ hour to set up. A more modern and more powerful, but more complex system such as [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29) or [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) or [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial_%28software%29) might take a whole hour. Spend an afternoon setting them up and learning the basic commands, you won't regret it.